# Customizing AAD Authentication logic

Tags: azure-active-directory

Is it possible to add/extend user authentication logic to AAD?

I want to be able to retrieve the user's password in an alternative way, then hand the password over to AAD to have it validated by AAD in the normal way.

From a high level, this is the authentication flow that I have in mind:

1. A user enters a system which requires authentication
2. The user is redirected to AAD for authentication
3. AAD redirects to my password retrieval engine
4. The user provides his password to the password retrieval engine
5. The password retrieval engine returns the password to AAD
6. The password retrieval engine redirects back to AAD
7. AAD performs password/user validation based on the user password from the password retrieval engine.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Username/Password authentication (`grant_type=password`) with AAD apps, although that flow is officially discouraged.

How that flow works in conjunction with the ADAL.NET library is explained in great detail here: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Acquiring-tokens-with-username-and-password

Be aware that your AAD app must be created as a "Native" app for this to work! "Web" apps (confidential clients) will raise the `AADSTS7002` error when trying to authenticate against those with username and password!

The AAD v2.0 password flow is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately, grant_type=password is not what I'm looking for. I want AAD to redirect to my system, which then interacts with the user to retrieve a user password, and then, my system returns the password to AAD and hands over control to AAD where the actual password validation takes place.I updated my question to make this more explicit.

Comment: @Merijn There are only three ways of integrating with AAD for authentication:
1. Let AAD handle the complete flow (user types credentials into login.microsoftonline.com page)
2. Set up Federation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/whatis-fed) - where credentials are only handled on-prem, but due to a trust relationship between your on-prem AD and AAD, you get an AAD authenticated user.
3. You collect credentials in a custom way, and pass them on to AAD for authentication directly - which is what I have described above.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. You can issue authentication tokens and create a custom authentication endpoint by adding an AuthController. Before a user can call the endpoint, he needs to call the AuthController with valid credentials in order to get a token which will be used in subsequent API calls.

This is by far the best [guide](https://www.newventuresoftware.com/blog/custom-authentication-with-azure-mobile-apps) I have seen so far for this. This [one](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mihansen/2018/03/25/azure-active-directory-authentication-easy-auth-with-custom-backend-web-api/) is also handy.

You could also have [a custom authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk#custom-auth) on the backend and AAD authentication on the frontend.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I'm afraid it is not the answer that I'm looking for.
I'm building a system where it is required that a password is obtained from the user in a proprietary way and that this password is then handed over to AAD which takes care of the actual authentication (including password validation). I assume it is possible to redirect the authentication process as a whole from AAD to an external identity provider, but that is also not what I'm looking for since I want AAD to be the login provider. Only the password needs to come via a distinct channel. Any ideas?